# Project can no longer build after Eclipse reinstall

Tags: java, android, eclipse, viewpagerindicator

My laptop recently crashed, so I got an old desktop PC up and running. Got Eclipse installed along with Android SDK.

But when I check my Android project out of Subversion into Eclipse, I get errors that suggest it cannot find the ViewPagerIndicator library (which I *did* already add to my workspace/projects as a library).

When I go to my Android project's properties, on the Android tab at the bottom, and add the ViewPagerIndicator as a library it shows a green checkbox:

[image]

I click OK, and dialog dismisses. But then when I try building I get these errors:

```
E:\Workspace\foobar\res\values\styles.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle'.
E:\Workspace\foobar\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.TabPageIndicator'.
```

If I go back into my project's properties on the Android tab, the same ViewPagerIndicator library that had a green checkbox not 3 seconds prior now has a red X, and there's question mark beside it in the "Project" column:

[image]

Both my project and the ViewPagerIndicator project are set to compile with Java 1.6 and are both targeted at SDK v16.

Oh, and yeah the same Subversion revision was building just fine on my laptop so all the files are identical as they were before.

Comment: It might sound stupid, but try removing the reference and then adding it back again.

Comment: I did. Several times. I've also removed and added the ViewPagerIndicator library back (import as existing Android code) several times. I even removed/added the library as a reference in my project.properties as "android.library.reference.1=C:/ViewPagerIndicator"

Comment: I am out of ideas now. Tough luck. Hope someone else can shed light on it.

Comment: have used clean/build project on the ViewPageIndicator build in eclipse? Some times I have to clean and build it explicitly before my project that uses it will compile.

Comment: it was an issue with me two days before, while trying to compile clients project,  I copied it into same workspace. and was also facing some xml resource error which was basically causing this issue too, Eclipse behave weirdly some time, All the best

Comment: is pageIndicator kind of one file object or another project? did you try to check if there is any `android.R` lib imported to classes (it should be removed btw, eclipse add it sometimes)?

Comment: i assume that you had projects out of workspace folder and then you imported them into workspace, right? Did you try right click on main project choose properties (last options) > java build path > projects tab> add here your library ? source folder has only `/gen/` and `/src/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't feel right posting this as the answer to my own question because I'm still at a loss for what I was doing wrong, if anything.

But I ended up removing both my project and the ViewPageIndicator library project from my workspace, then re-adding them back. Everything worked. Go figure. Maybe this will help someone else.